# HTML5 Datalist not appearing in chrome inside table for more than 1 row

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, datalist

I am facing a strange issue in Chrome in windows. I am working on a table grid and for one of the cell i need to show the autosuggest feature when user will type more that 2 character I amm assigning the Input box as `list` attribute with `id` same as `datalist` id. I am able to see `datalist` working properly for 1 row but when I try to increase the row count more than 1 I am not able to see the data list auto suggestions. Its working fine in `IE11`

Comment: We can't provide a good answer without having some code to work with, that reproduce the issue ... and I'm pretty sure you know this :)